# Matching two char type arrays in a for loop, for loop not excecuting correctly

Tags: java, for-loop, multidimensional-array, compare

Kind of hard to explain whats going on here. I am making hangman in java for an extra credit assignment. I want to check if the letter the user inputs is in the random word. I have a two dimensional char array. The 0 column is for each letter of the answer and the 1 column is for the correctly guessed letters.

```
    char[] usedLetters =new char[guesses];
    char[][] checker = new char[wordSize][2];
    char[] answer = new char[wordSize];
    String tempAnswer=word.randomWord();
    System.out.println(tempAnswer);
    answer=tempAnswer.toCharArray();
    for(int i = 0;i<wordSize;i++)
    {
        checker[i][0]=answer[i];
    }

    System.out.println("Enter your first guess!");
    char let=scan.next().charAt(0);

    for(int i = 0; i<wordSize; i++)
    {
        if(checker[i][0]==let)
        {
            checker[i][1]=let;
            System.out.println("found in" + i);
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("not found in" + i);
        }
    }

    usedLetters[g]=let;
    System.out.println("Guesses so far: " +g);
    System.out.print("Letters used so far: ");
```

The problem arises in the second for loop. Niether of the if else statements are printing to the console. I cannot solve this problem.
Here is what ive got in the console:

There are 127142 words to choose from

How long is the word you would like to guess?

9

How many guesses would you like?

10

butanones

Enter your first guess!

b

Guesses so far: 1

Letters used so far:

Notice how it completely skips both if else outputs! I have tried so many different ways but it keeps ignoring my matching for loop. Any suggestions?

As requested, this is the beginning of the Hangman class. For anyone with more than 6 months of programming experience this will look horrible.

```
public class Hangman
{
    private Scanner scan;
    private int wordSize;
    private Words word;
    private int guesses;
    private boolean winner;
    public void setup()
    {
        scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        word = new Words();
        System.out.println("How long is the word you would like to guess?");
        int wordSize=scan.nextInt();
        word.setGameWordList(wordSize);
        System.out.println("How many guesses would you like?");
        guesses=scan.nextInt();
    }
public void play()
    {
        int g = 1;
        char[] usedLetters =new char[guesses];
        char[][] checker = new char[wordSize][2];
        char[] answer = new char[wordSize];
        String tempAnswer=word.randomWord();
        System.out.println(tempAnswer);
        answer=tempAnswer.toCharArray();
        for(int i = 0;i<wordSize;i++)
        {
            checker[i][0]=answer[i];
        }

        System.out.println("Enter your first guess!");
        char let=scan.next().charAt(0);

        for(int i = 0; i<wordSize; i++)
        {
            if(checker[i][0]==let)
            {
                checker[i][1]=let;
                System.out.println("found in" + i);
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("not found in" + i);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Are you sure `wordSize` isn't 0?

Comment: yes i do it in my setup method

Comment: In that case, `wordSize` wouldn't keep its value in your guesser. Maybe you meant `word = new Words(); System.out.println("blablabla"); wordSize=scan.nextInt();`

Comment: I'm confused. Sorry but I set the value of wordSize in my setup method. So if I use it in a different method it equals zero? It is initialized outside of the setup method as a private type.

Comment: You had `int wordSize` in your setup method, so it likely is 0, unless you've set it somewhere else. Please post your setup method and your entire guesser method in your question.

Comment: That would explain a lot though, I will play with it a little bit more.

Comment: Just print `wordSize` right after `char let=scan.next().charAt(0);` and see what you get.

Comment: You were right >.< thanks, I've got so much to learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your setup method, just take out the `int` in `int wordSize=scan.nextInt();`.

A new variable `wordSize` becomes local to `setup()` and won't keep its value in `play()`. You need to set the instance variable `wordSize` instead.